# highlight the link after user has clicked it

Tags: jquery

i want to highlight the link when user has clicked it and maintain the highlight as long as user visit that link. i have tried it using jquery but to no avail. so any help/suggestions.thanks in advance.
my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=<?php echo BASE_URL?>/js/jquery.js></script>
<div class="menu_short">
    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL?>/index.html">Home</a>  
    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL?>/1.html">1</a> 
    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL?>/2.html">2</a>
    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL?>/3.html">3</a>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".menu_short a").click(function(){
            $(".menu_short a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        })
    })
</script>

css:
.menu_short{

    float:left;
    clear:both;
    }
.menu_short a, .menu_short a:link,  .menu_short a:visited {
    font:bold 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    padding:0 15px;
    }

.menu_short a:hover{
    color: #ffd634;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
.menu_short a:active {
    color:#ffd634;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "as long as user visit that link" ? Why is `:visited` not enough ?

Comment: @dystroy can you please elaborate it. and how do i use that in above code. tried it searched it.but no avail.can you drop in some help/suggestions

Comment: You are already using it, `.menu_short a, .menu_short a:link,  .menu_short a:visited` makes the link white when it's been visited by a user. If you want to only change the link WHILE the user is on the another site thats an entirely different problem.

Comment: @Bulk yes the link is white but when you hover on it, link is yellow and i want that yellow link while the user is in that link. i mean by default all link is white, now when i hover on 1 link color changes to yellow and now i want that yellow color on that link as long as user doesnt leave the page of that link.

Comment: There is no way to do what you want with out some fairly complicated server side code, and then ONLY if that link is to a page on the same site.

Comment: @bulk oh so :(
know anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for highlighting the link and make it active after user has clicked i coded it as
code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=<?php echo BASE_URL?>/js/jquery.js></script>
<div class="menu_short">
    <a class="<?php echo $page_code=='1'?"current":"";?>" href="<?php echo BASE_URL?>/index.html">Home</a>  
    <a class="<?php echo $page_code=='2'?"current":"";?>" href="<?php echo BASE_URL?>/1.html">1</a> 
    <a class="<?php echo $page_code=='3'?"current":"";?>" href="<?php echo BASE_URL?>/2.html">2</a>
    <a class="<?php echo $page_code=='4'?"current":"";?>" href="<?php echo BASE_URL?>/3.html">3</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.menu_short a{
color: #E26EFF;
}
.menu_short a:hover{
background: #FF6ADA;
color:#2362A5;
}
.menu_short a.current {
background:#FF6ADA;
color:#2362A5;
}
```

where $page_code is the numeric code given for each page as for index page

```
function index(){
$data['page_code']=1;
}
```